# how to add <hr/> tag and utm tags in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

I have two requirements, and im not sure is those things possible in AS3.
Anyway I'll explain what I want.

first, I need to show an `<hr/>` tag after the description, its an rss widget so need to seperate with each rss post with a border or hr. Its not possible to make it manually because its came from xml. I'll give you the existing script with me.

second, I need to add utm tag after the urls to trace the clicks, this is actually I need to add after the links 'utm_source=rsswidget', you'll get an idea by seeing the script below

```
   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

var xml:XML;

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
style.setStyle(".heading", {fontWeight:"bold", color:"#6184b7", fontSize:12});
style.setStyle("body", {fontStyle:"italic"});

xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    var il:XMLList = xml.channel.item;
    for(var i:uint=0; i<il.length(); i++)
    {

t.setStyle("styleSheet", style);
t.htmlText = "<a href='"+il.link.text()[0]+"' class='heading'>"+il.title.text()[0]+"</a>"+"\<br />"+il.description.text()[0]+"\<br/><br/>"+"<a href='"+il.link.text()[1]+"' class='heading'>"+il.title.text()[1]+"</a>"+"\<br />"+il.description.text()[1]+"\<br /><br />"+"<a href='"+il.link.text()[2]+"' class='heading'>"+il.title.text()[2]+"</a>"+"\<br />"+il.description.text()[2];
    }

}
```

t stands for text area.

hope your replies get soon..

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HR tag isn't supported in Actionscript. My suggestion would be to just use a loop to parse through all of your XML elements, and add the HR visuals as movieclips from your library after every entry... perhaps like so (btw, this is all pseudo-code - I haven't tested it):

```
var xmlData:String = "<channel><item><link>My link</link> <description>My description</description> </item> <item> <link>My link</link> <description>My description</description> </item> <item> <link>My link</link> <description>My description</description> </item>  <item> <link>My link</link> <description>My description</description> </item> </channel>"
var xml:XML = new XML(xmlData);

var buffer = 5
var ypos = 0

for(var i:uint=0; i<xml.item.length(); i++){
    // create the textfield and populate it with your data
    var t = new TextField()
    t.border = true
    t.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT
    t.multiline = true
    t.wordWrap = true
    t.y = ypos
    t.htmlText = "<a href='"+xml.item[i].link+"' class='heading'>"+xml.item[i].link+"</a>"+"\<br />"+xml.item[i].description
    this.addChild(t)

    // create one HR
    var hr = new HorizontalLine() // this would be a movieclip in your library with the linkage HorizontalLine
    hr.y = t.y + t.height + buffer
    this.addChild(hr)

        // positioning
    ypos = hr.y + buffer
}
```

Also, here's an FLA saved to CS4 if you're still stuck: http://clearmpls.com/temp/xml-list.zip

Comment: by the way Im not sure how to work on your code with my script I'll provide my full script here, so can you edit it once again for me..? You can see the script on mydescription above I just edited though.

Comment: I edited my answer then - I THINK it'll work, but I'm not sure without knowing what your XML data looks like. The main takeaway is this: create each node of your XML data as a separate textfield and hr, then just loop through all of your nodes and dynamically create your hr with a movieclip/sprite/etc from your library, then position then after each other after each loop iteration.

Comment: I edited it again with a working example. I kinda just assumed you were working with an RSS feed, so that was the XML data I used.